# Problem with the datepicker plugin in QueryBuilder

Tags: javascript, datepicker, query-builder

I'm using QueryBuilder and I have a search that is of type date. The problem is that I'm getting an error because of the Plugin Datapicker, but I do not know what the reason for the error, can anyone help me?

My code:

```
        {
        id: 'pac_dt_validate',
        label: 'Data Validade',
        type: 'date',
        operators: ['equal', 'less', 'less_or_equal', 'greater', 'greater_or_equal', 'between'],
        validation: {
          format: 'dd/mm/yy'
        },
        plugin: 'datepicker',
        plugin_config: {
          dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
          dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado'],
          dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
          dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
          monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
          monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez'],
          nextText: 'Próximo',
          prevText: 'Anterior',
          todayBtn: 'linked',
          todayHighlight: true,
          autoclose: true
        }


    <script src="{{ asset('vendor/adminlte/vendor/jquery-builder/js/query-builder.standalone.min.js') }}"></script>    
    <script src="{{ asset('vendor/adminlte/vendor/jquery-builder/query-builder.pt-BR.js') }}"></script>                
    <script src="{{ asset('vendor/adminlte/vendor/momentJs/moment-with-locales.min.js') }}"></script>
```

The Bootstrap Js has already been imported, so that's not the problem, the error that appears is this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: n[i.plugin] is not a function
at c.createRuleInput (query-builder.standalone.min.js:7)
at c.updateRuleFilter (query-builder.standalone.min.js:7)
at n.update (query-builder.standalone.min.js:7)
at n.dispatch (jquery.js:2)
at n.y.handle (jquery.js:2)
```

Can someone help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the bootstrap-datepicker.js. Remember that this import needs to be after the import of bootstrap.js.

After that, you will need to import the bootstrap-datepicker.css to style the plugin